# Chromium Embedded WPF Browser control redraws every second whenever document changes. Workaround?

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

It seems like a bug in package (v49.0.1). To reproduce - create new WPF project, set its architecture to x86 or x64, add CefSharp.Wpf NuGet package. Restart VS, compile. Add ChromiumBrowser to MainWinoow.xaml with Address property set to any URL, like "http://stackoverflow.com". Run application.

What I see is browser redrawing every second, completely unusable. WinForms version works fine. Since my whole big project depends on CEF - any clues what to do? What can cause control to redraw like crazy?

**Update**:

I found what triggers it: any DOM change. Static pages are displayed correctly. I also found that v47.0.4 works fine with WPF and dynamic content. I'd rather avoid using it because of breaking changes in API introduced in version 49.0.0.

It seems like a bug, actually it's know issue posted on GitHub as issue #1666:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1666

It's also in release notes for v49.0.0
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v49.0.0

See the answer for workaroud I found.

Comment: And in previous versions you don't see this problem? If not - just use previous version.

Comment: Works in 47.0.4, but there were breaking API changes after this version. I'm not even sure if it exposes all needed functionality. Well, at least I made sure it's a bug.

Comment: Well you can try to write them about this issue. Maybe there is some configuration setting to fix this behavior, who knows. I use 47 version fine for quite some time (though I use winforms inside wpf, because wpf version uses offscreen rendering which has too bad performance for my goals).

Comment: I've filed a bug report on their GitHub project. Meanwhile I cloned version 51.0.0 and... It works. So I copied all binaries from working example to empty WPF project. And it's broken in exactly the same way. I don't get it! Code in WPF SimpleMainWindow is IDENTICAL with what I created. In my project - browser flickers, in their project - it works perfectly. All binaries are copied from their project. If I copy my EXE to their working example - it's broken. Control flickers. It's a kind of black voodoo magic to me.

Comment: This is a known issue, see the release notes for more details. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v49.0.0

Comment: I'd also note that `51.0.0` has yet to be released, there will be a `-pre` release shortly, more information will be provided on this issue when it's released. Anyone requiring information on this issue should follow https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1634 (which you would have found linked in the release notes).

Comment: I think that because you've been able to isolate the problem and also provide an answer then by definition this question *isn't* too broad, so I'm voting to reopen. I'd suggest you take the update section from your question and add it to your answer instead.

Comment: @amaitland: My mistake, I tried to correct obvious issues with my question and the answer, I promise also to do my best to contribute to the project starting with doing more research and testing related to CEF and CefSharp new branches. My current big project depends heavily on CefSharp so it would be a nice test for many features like new custom scheme handling and more.

Comment: Contributions are welcome! Best place to discuss is https://gitter.im/cefsharp/CefSharp#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
public partial class App : Application {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        var cefSettings = new CefSettings();
        cefSettings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
        Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
    }

}
```

As a workaround some specific options can be set with `SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs()` in `CefSettings` object passed to `Cef.Initialize()`. This should be called before any CEF control is created, best in App.xaml.cs in `OnStartup()` override.

Comment: The function is documented, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Core/CefSettings.h#L250

Comment: If you use this method `DevTools` won't draw correctly. See the release notes for more information. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v49.0.0

Comment: If your unhappy with the general state of the documentation, how about helping out?

Comment: @amaitland: I will. I was too new to the project, but I'll definitely contribute. Nothing helps learning the API like using it in a real world code and solve some issues :) For now - I would put the workaround directly in release notes, since it could be not obvious for new users or users upgrading from v47 or earlier.

Comment: I've changed the heading from `Notes` to `Known Issues`, should be clearer. The biggest problem appears to be that people just don't take the time to read the release notes. Contributions are most welcome :)